# datepicker strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have strange error. All libraries that needs i included like on theri site but it still does not work. Why? What i missed?
In console i have

[image]

Index.chstml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ useCurrent: false });
        $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.hide", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "POST",
                data: { test: $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').date().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.results').html(response);
                }
            });
            debugger;
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(DateTime? test)
    {
        return Json("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: add css files first, then js files

Comment: The `dp.hide` event has a [`date` property](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dphide), you can try using it instead of  `date()`. Your ajax data field will be: `data: { test: e.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') }`

Answer (score 0):

try

use change event

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "POST",
                data: { test: $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date() ==null ? $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date() : $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.results').html(response);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Now it do not raise error in javascript. But it pass null to controller.

Answer (score 0):

First, add Jquery file link if you put jquery in your app folder

add jquery datepicker files

```js
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

now write below code:

```
 $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker(
{
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    yearRange: "-80: +0",
    setDate: new Date()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code work correctly for me check the Jquery library and try to restart your computer if not

**Edit**

I try your code without Layout maybe your problem in the Layout
[image]